# Different animations for multiple instances of ng-leave?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I'm using AngularJS to build a simple site. There's a page called 'Project Index', which can be linked to Project Detail and About. I want to have one kind of animation applied to ng-leave of Project Index when visitor going to About, and another kind of animation applied to ng-leave of Project Index when visitor going to Project Detail.

Is this possible and what would be the best way?

Comment: it is possible,one way (maybe the easiest) is to use your CSS to customize animations

Comment: you can check this link out     
https://scotch.io/tutorials/animating-angularjs-apps-ngview

Comment: @maioman how would I target different instances using CSS?

Comment: how are you animating it at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ui-router, try to use

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 

function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ ... })
```

Add some variable to this function,

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
   if toState.name == 'about'
   $scope.leaveClass = true
   else if toState.name == 'Project Detail'
   $scope.leaveClass = false
```

then add class to your ui-view

```
<div ui-view ng-class="{'aboutLeave':$scope.leaveClass,'detailLeave':!$scope.leaveClass}">
```

in css use animations

```
.aboutLeave.ng-leave{...}
.detailLeave.ng-leave{...}
```

I didn't tried this but it should work :)

Comment: And use you'r state names, variable and others, i just provided fast way you could do this